# Calling Model.add() with a variable as parameter

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I'm trying to import some data using django ORM. So, I have built a script that will probably be filled from an excel sheet.

Then, through the python console, I'm doing : `execfile('import.py')`.

I'll have something like this in my import.py :

```
from catalog.models import (User, Product, Project)

PROJECT_FILLER_USER_ID = 1
PROJECT_TITLE = "Some Title"
PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = "Some description"
IS_PROJECT_ACTIVE = True

f = User.objects.get(id=PROJECT_FILLER_USER_ID)
p = Project.objects.create(filler=f, title=PROJECT_TITLE, description=PROJECT_DESCRIPTION, active=IS_PROJECT_ACTIVE)

PROJECT_PRODUCTS_LIST = "1, 2, 3, 8"

# Lists are filled with id with ',' as separator
p.products.add(PROJECT_PRODUCTS_LIST)
```

So basically, I want it to do stuffs like, creating the Project and then add its content from other models.

For example, after creating the project, something like this : `p.products.add(1, 2, 3, 8)` should occur. But it looks like Django doesn't like when I'm passing a list of id as a string.

How can I deal with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first create a list, `"1, 2, 3 ,8"` is a string not a list, so it's far from working, you need `[1, 2, 3, 8]`.

Secondly, for `M2M` field you need to call `add` like this when you have a list of ids:

```
project_list = [1, 2, 3, 8]
p.prodeucts.add(*project_list)
```

The star here is python way to unpack argument list. One `*` will work for list/tuple argument, while `**` will work for dictionaries. Check [PEP448](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) doc for more details.

Comment: Is the '*' character intended there ? If so, why ?

Comment: Alright, thanks, quick other question, can I use a string for a `DateTimeField` in the `create()` ?

Comment: No, you need to create a datetime object first. Use python datetime module to create a datetime: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: hm I managed to make it with something like `create(date="2016-01-15T17:18:44.258843Z", ...)` and it looks like it worked with no issue

Comment: Have you checked your data? Does the field return a correct datetime object?

Comment: The field is in my database with its value. However I'm using a sqlite database which doesn't have date type, so it might not work on another database like psql

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but maybe sqlite does work with it. Are you able to use the field in django shell? Like doing a `object.date.year`?

Comment: Hmm, nope, I can do `object.date`, it returns the string. But I can't do `object.date.year` (no attribute 'year' in str).
So I should do something like `d = datetime.strptime('2016-01-15T17:18:44Z','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')` and then in my `create()` : `create(date=d, ...)` ?
Also, what's the syntax if I have a dot and 6 more digits after the seconds ?

Comment: Yea, create datetime object first then `create` is the way to go. Sorry I'm not sure how to deal with the digits after second as I've never seen it happen to me. You can do string manipulation to cut them, can't you?

Comment: Actually it's %f for microseconds. But I can't do that because my DateTimeField is naive, and it expects an aware date

Comment: Ah, my mind somehow failed to link your `6 digits` to `microseconds`. To make a datetime aware, do: `from django.utils import timezone` then `timezone.make_aware(your_datetime_obj, timezone.get_current_timezone())`